# record does not exist or has been deleted.\\n(record: account.move.line(5398,), user: 7) in odoo while updating

Tags: python, django, api, python-requests, odoo

I'm getting record does not exist or has been deleted.\n(record: account.move.line(5398,), user: 7) error while updating data to odoo. Following is my code can anyone help to solve this problem.

```
   import xmlrpc.client
   endpoint_url = "/api/account.move/"
   obj = get_object_or_404(OrderItem, order__id=order_id)
   invoice_date = obj.order.created_on
   name = obj.product.varient_name
   price = obj.total
   quantity = obj.quantity
   payment_source =  obj.order.payment_method
   payment_reference = obj.order.order_number
   common = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/common'.format(url))
   uid = common.authenticate(db, username, password, {})
   models = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/object'.format(url))
   ids = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'account.move', 'search_read', [[['source_document', '=', payment_reference]]], {'fields': ['partner_id', 'id']})
   invoice_id = ids[0]['id']
   partner_id_ = ids[0]['partner_id'][0]
   headers = {
            "access-token":tokens,
            "Content-type":"application/jsonp",
            "Cookie":session_id
      }
   api_invoice_line_id = [(1, invoice_id,{'name':name, 'price_unit':price, 'quantity':quantity})]
   data = {
      "partner_id":partner_id_,
      "invoice_date":str(invoice_date),
      "move_type":"out_invoice",
      "__api__invoice_line_ids":str(api_invoice_line_id),
      "payment_source":payment_source,
      "source_document": payment_reference,
      "rider":rider_name,
       "ref":""
   }
   datas_ = json.dumps(data, indent=4)
   req = requests.put(url+endpoint_url+str(invoice_id), headers=headers, data=datas_)
   if req.status_code == 200:
      status = "Update Successful"
   else:
      status = str(req.text)
   return status
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your code is failing because of the tuple you give to insert/update data in `__api__invoice_line_ids`.

I suppose it's some `account.move.line` Many2many or One2many field.

I see you are using the command 1 with `invoice_id` (an `account.move` id) and some data in a dict.

The problem here is that you are then trying to add that in the field pointing to `account.move.line`. So your ID 5398 is the `account.move` id, not an `account.move.line` id.

Not sure what your goal is to achieve here. If it's to push/update some account.move records with new data, change your `__api__invoice_line_ids` to point to account.move.

If your goal is to push/update some `account.move.line` records, then you better loop on the `line_ids` of your `invoice_id` :)

If I wasn't clear on something or you have any other question don't hesitate asking !